# String to Date; Format of input varies

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat, string-conversion

For the project I'm working on at the moment I need to convert a *String* to a *Date*. Unfortunately the date and time aren't formatted the same in all the *Strings* that need to be converted. In the current values we often see something like **2011-06-25T22:44:12** or **2011-06-25 22:49:01** (notice the T?).

I know how to convert a *String* to a *Date* using *SimpleDateFormat*, but since I don't know what the format the input will have this doesn't seem like the right approach. I was wondering if there is a way to add several 'formats' to a *DateFormat* object or perhaps there's a *DateFormat* class that can auto-detect the format?

The other approach I was thinking of is using some if/else statements and regular expressions on the *String* to figure out what format is being used and use the *SimpleDateFormat* class that matches with it, but I'm pretty sure there should be an easier way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several variations, not just one with 'T' and another with a space, I believe an if/then/else with several regular expressions and matching SimpleDateFormats is the way to go.

Comment: I was thinking of that approach, but it seems like a lot of work when having a lot of variations (I really hate writing regular expressions). Perhaps I could iterate through a _List_ of _SimpleDateFormat_ objects, try to parse the string and if it succeeds, break the loop. But I hope there's a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

The T inside is because it is the standard ISO format for date http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601. Mind however that this format with 'T' is only one of several variations you might see when date comes as ISO 8601 (one of the variations is stripped out time, another is with following timezone specicification).

If you know that your date will be conforming to the ISO 8601 standard (this is very often for well-specified XML - when you use XSD date fields conform to ISO 8601) then Java's SimpleDateFormat is not enough - it is too simple... You might revert to JodaTime library instead - Joda Time has already ISO 8601 formatter ready for you to use:
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html

Edited: I would not implement any complex regexp matching - it makes code difficult to maintain and understand in a long run (especially if you can have many sources in many formats)

The proposal is - find out which provider uses which format and employ strategy pattern: formatter = DateFormatterStrategyChooser.getFormatter(String source). Divide et impera.

And in case you are not 100% sure which source brings what kind of date - you can still use UmbrellaFormatter(Collection) and go through each formatter in sequence until one succeeds.. This is best for maintainability rather than relying on obscure and complex rules.

Comment: The JodaTime library seems like a nice library, but unfortunately I can't be sure that the input will always comply with the ISO8601 standard. The files I'm processing are delivered by various parties and unfortunately we see different formats every now and then. That's why I think an approach which uses a list of possible formats would be the easiest.

Comment: Sure. Then you really have to build set of parsers and parse them one-by-one until one succeeds (I'd build UmbrellaParser passing it a set of parsers at construction time and then go one-by-one until one succeeds).... Only hope that you won't get YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-DD-MM  from two different places. They are sometimes undistinguishable. Another (better) option would be to find out which provider uses which format and employ strategy pattern: formatter =   DateFormatterStrategyChooser.getFormatter(String source)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I guess I'll go with the UmbrellaParser approach.

Answer (score 0):

Test for presence of the 'T', if it it present, parse the string and replace with a space. Now you can use a Date Formatter to create an Date object.

Comment: The given formats are just two of several possible formats, so I'm afraid this isn't the best solution to the problem.